# How to interact with tezos blockchain by using python?

Tags: rpc, python

I want to create a python script in which I need to create some functions like
1-GetTransactionByHash
2-GetBlockByHash
3-GetBalanceOfWallet

I want to ask that how could I do it by using python in ethereum we can do it by using web3.py but in tezos how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PyTezos](https://pytezos.org/quick_start.html#introduction).

Interactive examples: https://pytezos.baking-bad.org/tutorials/02.html

Comment: can you tell me how can I get the transaction by hash?

Comment: For getting a transaction by hash you need to lookup every block starting from the head block until you find it. For this specific case you should use an indexer.

Comment: If you want to use pytezos, you can do (e.i. `pytezos.shell.blocks[1129600:1129700].find_operation('onw8xuA8SKNdJo4VUf5vyhJKRmggWRVuLAavCbRnmQvE1zr65KF')`). It will query every block from level 1129600 to 1129700.

Comment: and if we don't know the block and we've just txHash we can't find it directly by using just txHash?

Comment: If the transaction hash is too old, you need an indexer. But if the transaction hash is recent, you can use the example above, where you can lookup from block `<head_block_level> minus <offset>` to `<head_block_level>`.

Comment: Can you share python code for it becaise I'm not getting it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140177/discussion-between-shahbaz-ali-and-rodrigo-quelhas).